# What would be RoR's equivalent to PHP Session?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, session

What would be Ruby on Rails equivalent to PHP Session?

Comment: umm, `session`. It's a web programming concept, not a PHP concept. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions

Answer (score 6):

Session is a general concept, it's not relative to PHP. Any server-side language has its own implementation to deal with sessions.

First result when googling 'ruby on rails sessions':
http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Read here about [sessions on RoR](http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6372-action-controller-session).

Basically you need to turn sessions on and off in your controllers. And then access it with something like:

```
@_session_val = session[:some_val]
```